# Run script as new content is loaded - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome Extension that will block all "Promoted by" ads on Pinterest, and I'm using this video as a starting point to teach myself how to write this out (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rymG9UmPuhM&t=532s). So far it's working when the page loads, but as I scroll and pinterest loads more pins, it doesn't apply to the newly loaded ads.

Below is the code I have so far (forgive my terrible DOM navigation with the parentElements. It's just a quick and dirty way of testing atm).

```
replaceText(document.body)

function replaceText(element) {
    if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
        element.childNodes.forEach(replaceText)
    } else if (element.nodeType === Text.TEXT_NODE) {
        if (element.textContent.match(/Promoted by/gi)) {
            element.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add("block");
        }
        element.textContent = element.textContent.replace(/Promoted by/gi, '***')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it would be by using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) in my opinion.
Here is how you could pull it off :

```
//Declare an observer using your replaceText function
let observer = MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(node) {
      replaceText(node);
    });
  });
});
//Start to listen to the document
observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

`childList` is used to listen to the children of body and `subtree` to listen to all descendants (i.e. children of children)